# Running commands in a docker container in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently I'm trying to run a container inside jenkins, to make calls to an aws ecr to find the latest image. To do this I need to set aws configure parameters, however I am at a loss why this doesn't work as the container is running as root as the USER command hasn't been defined.

However whenever I run the container I receive the following message

```
+ docker inspect -f . mikesir87/aws-cli
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 112:114 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx@2 -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx@2:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx@2:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx@2@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx@2@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** mikesir87/aws-cli cat
$ docker top de3435a8a54f6afa42f8136a57ec67b2720c655328f1aadc0addeb412a92240f -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx@2
[Pipeline] sh
+ aws configure set aws_access_key_id key
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.aws'
```

What I don't understand is if I try and launch this container from bash I don't get this permission denied error. See below for jenkinsfile

```
        stage('Check Container Version')
        {
            agent
            {
                docker { image 'mikesir87/aws-cli' }
            }
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    sh '''pwd'''
                    sh ''' aws configure set aws_access_key_id key'''

                }
            }
        }
```

The container was grabbed from docker hub and below is the dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine

ARG CLI_VERSION=1.18.37

RUN apk -uv add --no-cache groff jq less && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir awscli==$CLI_VERSION

WORKDIR /aws

CMD sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container is not actually running with the root user inside when executed as a Docker agent in Jenkins Pipeline. You can notice in the Pipeline output above that:

> docker run -t -d -u 112:114 ...

Since you want to work around the permissions issue with running the container with the root user inside, you can modify the agent arguments to allow this:

```
agent {
  docker { image 'mikesir87/aws-cli'
           args '-u root:root' 
  }
}
```

and then your container user should have the permissions necessary for the AWS configure.

Comment: Cheers Matt just noticed it myself aswell = facepalm. But least someone else who see this problem won't hit the same problem.

Comment: @ION I had a really similar problem myself months ago, so you are certainly not alone, and it was why Ii recognized what was going on.